# Display values on top of bars

Tags: charts, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

How can I display values on top of the chart bars as shown in the picture?

[image: Chart]

I'm using LibreOffice 4.4.2.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Double-click on chart to select it;
2. Menu `Insert` -> `Data labels`;
3. Tick Show Value as number, select Placement: Center:

   [image]

You may adjust font color, font attributes and so on by double-clicking on one of the labels.